# How to convert C char array to bytes directly

Tags: racket

I have c-string style [array](https://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/C_Array_Types.html) if_name defined:

```
(define-cstruct _ifreq ([ifr_name (_array _byte IFNAMSIZE)]
                    ;; ommited ...
                    ))
```

I can access individual elements by (`array->ref`) and through recursion create list from it. Then use (`list->bytes`) to get lisp data structure. I am curious if there is a simpler way without need for list creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racket comes with mutable byte strings for just such an occasion!

```
(require ffi/unsafe)

(define (byte-array->bytes array)
  (let* ([len   (array-length array)]
         [byte* (make-bytes len)])
    (for ([i (in-range len)])
      (bytes-set! byte* i (array-ref array i)))
    byte*))
```